# Does というのも used as "because" always require a から or んだ at the end?

Tags: grammar, sentence

Found this sentence from social media, and put it through DeepL:

ほぼ毎朝5時に起きます。朝に強い。**というのも**、小学校5年生から新聞配達をしていました。

I get up almost every morning at 5am. I am strong in the morning.
**This is because** I have been delivering newspapers since the 5th grade of elementary school.

It seems like this usage of というのも falls under these kind of usages as per my dictionary:

② 理由をあとに述べる意を表す。「社長みずからが来たと言うのも、社運にかかわる事態だからだ」

③ （副詞的に用いて）そうなったわけは。「優勝した。と言うのも、監督がよかったからだ」「と言うのも、こんな話を聞いたんです」

The dictionary usages add から or んだ in the end in their examples for listing a reason, and multiple of my grammar resources also pair というのは・も and から・んだ・ため to be used together, but this sentence does not include the latter.
Is this pairing really needed when listing a reason with the construction, as if not why? It seems odd that this can mean "because" without the aid of something like から.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s usually followed up by an expression that more clearly denotes a reason, such as から. However, this requirement is not so strong as when you begin the sentence with 朝に強いのは to say the same thing. The following sentence is weird, if not simply wrong.

> [x] 朝に強いのは小学校5年生から新聞配達をしていました。

This is because without an expression like から we don’t know the speaker meant to explain a reason with の. For example, the sentence could’ve ended like this.

> 朝に強いのはみんな知っています。

In comparison, と言うのも alone is enough to prepare the listener to listen for a reason and this reduces the requirement for an explicit marker.

The sentence would’ve still sounded more natural if it ended with 〜んです as you suggested, though.

> というのも、小学校5年生から新聞配達をしていたんです。

By the way, the same can be said about the second sentence.

> 朝に強いんです。